# Java Inheritance - implementation and extension

Tags: java, inheritance

I have class `A`, and interfaces `I`, `J`, `K` and `L`

I then have `AB` and finally class `C`

```
class AB extends A

class C extends AB implements I, J, K, L
```

Interface `I`  requires a method `void setSize(int size)`.

Class `A` already has a method `setSize(int size){this.size = size;}`

Am I correct in saying I still have to override class `A`'s `setSize` and implement `setSize` in class `C` to get the implementation correct?

Comment: Why do you think so? Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: FYI, I, J, K, and L are called Interfaces,  not Implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class provides the method `setSize(int)` (matching the signature of the interface), then it will satisfy the interface requirements. If it inherits a matching method (not abstract) from a superclass, then it is provided; you don't need to override it.

Comment: It was wierd my IDE was telling me I had to reimplement and giving me an error...but it was compiling ok.  Then throwing non specific run time errors...but I am sure I can work through those.  And sorry yes of course they are interfaces...my bad.

Answer (score 2):

If any of superclasses has method with required signature, you don't need to implement it in your classes.